# integral applications

Tags: calculus, integration

I have attempted this question several times and i am not coming up with the correct answer and it is starting to frustrate me!! if anyone can point me in the direction id appreciate it!!!

QUESTION IS:
Let $s(t)$ denote the position of a particle at time $t$, and let $v$ and $a$ be the velocity and acceleration respectively. The particle is moving according to the data $a(t)=t-2$, $s(0)=10$, $v(0)=2$.
Find a function describing the position of the particle.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;a(t)=s''(t)\\{}\\
\bullet&\;\;\int(t-2)dt=\frac12t^2-2t+C\;,\;\;C=\text{ a constant}\\
\bullet&\;\;v(t)=s'(t)=\int a(t)dt\end{align*}$$

Comment: thanks...i got s(t)= (t^3)/6 -t^2 +Ct + D, where D is a constant                then  s(0)=10 therefore D=10    then v(0)=2-> C=2 so s(t)=(t^3)/6 -t^2 +2t+10 but my answer is wrong??

Comment: Exactly, @user132138...now just input the given values to find out what the constants are. Way to go.

Comment: Nice work @user132138! Can you see how to solve for each of your constants? That's where your given values of $v(0) = 2$ and $s(0) = 10$ come in to play!

Comment: not really ???? @amWhy

Comment: If you did copy correctly the data then the answer looks correct (trying to read mathematics without LaTeX is hard...)...why do you say you're wrong, @user132138 ?

Comment: im using an online homework system called Webwork and i have input this answer but it keeps telling me im wrong and i cant see where??

Comment: Check **carefully** the given data, &user13213...and don't overtrust machines.

Comment: thanks very much appreciate the help these questions are very complex!! @DonAntonio

Comment: @user132138 , any time.